# DevExpress Winforms Report Designer(when program running) Object DataSource bind to table to get dynamic result

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

im trying to create report with table in winforms application.
I need to use object as datasource (assembly), and when im trying to bind List to table i only getting one row. Im sure i have more items in collection. I creating datasource and map with each field in class.
I tryed everything, and also i cant find any example of this on the devexpress website.

I added Id to the collection, but didn't helped.

[image]

Some code:

This how im binding data:

```
     var incidentCardReportAssetsInformationItems = new List<IncidentCardReportAssetsInformationItem>();

            foreach (var assetsInformation in assetsAssignedToIncidentWithTimesInformation)
            {
                var item = new IncidentCardReportAssetsInformationItem
                {
                    AssetName = assetsInformation.Asset?.Name,
                    AssetOrganization = assetsInformation.Asset?.UserOrganizationUnit?.CodeNumber,
                    EventStartTime = assetsInformation.EventStartTime.ToString("F", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                    TypeOfEvent = assetsInformation.TypeOfEvent
                };

                incidentCardReportAssetsInformationItems.Add(item);
            }
```

In class this is the list which i trying to bind to the table:

```
        public List<IncidentCardReportAssetsInformationItem> IncidentCardReportAssetsInformationItems { get; set; }
```

Comment: Try to bind the List to report.DataSource

Comment: i bind whole object to report datasource and in this object is this list

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your labels in the 'Detail' area.

Comment: Thanks for the comment ,but still i getting only one record

Comment: @ 逍遥子k added , u want maybe something more specific?